# Error establishing a database connection using Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have problem with my Wordpress site, it was working normally, Suddenly this message start to appear

Error establishing a database connection Wordpress

I tried the following things (no one is working and I still have the same problem till now)

I checked my wp_config.php for db name and credential and every thing is fine and I tried to repair db by adding `WP_ALLOW_REPAIR` and this scripts shows that every thing is okay.

I added test file to my website to see if the db credentials is correct like following

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'myUserName', 'myPassword');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

and it's print Connected successfully

I tried to disable plugins by changing the name of the plugins folder, but same problem.

Comment: Is this intermittent, or permanent? If the former, perhaps you db server is failing under load

Comment: it's permanent now, i can not access my website

Comment: Well if this happened without code changes, chances are its a server issue, what does your host say?

Comment: they said the server is working fine, logfiles do not contain any info about shutdown or any strange behavior . check your config

Comment: I'd suggest verifying that the permissions on your wp_config.php (and parent folders) are correct, and that your .htaccess files are in order. If that doesn't help, try restarting the server and see if things break in a fashion that's useful in getting your host's attention.

Comment: Also, make sure to get switched over to mysqli as soon as possible

Comment: In your sample php code, check also that mysql_select functions is able to select your database: there could be some rights issues for your db only.

Comment: did you try to add this to your wp-config.php ?

define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

Comment: Can you access the admin area? If so, double-check that it isn't related to caching. If not, it's related to yur db credentials, which are likely incorrect.

Comment: 1- Debug as mentioned by @EliasRodrigues
2- Try to verify you db credentials
3- Try to update wordpress

Comment: Have you tried adding a database select call to your test script? sometimes the connection is fine, but there may be problems with the tables.

Answer (score 4):

**Try to change your test file to use the wp-config file.**

```
     <?php
     //PATH TO YOUR FILE
     require_once('path/to/wp-config.php');
     //using wp-config variables 
     $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
     if (!$link) {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }
     echo 'Connected successfully';
     mysql_close($link);
     ?>
```

**If this is working you dont have a code issue - you have a server/connectivity issue.**

Answer (score 0):

Your test demonstrates that you can successfully connect to the MySQL with the user:pass to localhost. But are you sure that the user can use the specific database?
Try to add mysql_select_db( $link, 'database_name' ) to your test code, something like this:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'myUserName', 'myPassword');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';

$use = mysql_select_db( $link, 'myDatabaseName' );

if( $use )
{
    echo "\n" .'Database selected!';
}

mysql_close($link);
?>
```

This is just a suggestion to be sure that everything is working fine.
As @Nimrod007 said: if everything now is working, the problem is not in the code and could be some server/connectivity issue.

Answer (score 0):

1st:  Maybe MAX_CONNECTION_LIMIT is the problem. If already max connection open. new connection not accepted. So ur WP Site and other database failed to connect to MYSQL SERVER.

so you will get Error establishing a database connection error.

2nd: Uses of RAM. if your RAM IS FULL. Mysql Server failed to start.

check mysql error logs.